# Table vertical Line Offset and Centering Problem using multicolumn

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, multicolumn

I use tabularx for a table and wanted to incorporate some multicolumns to merge cells for readability reasons. Using multicolumns though results in a slight offset of the right vertical line. Also the text is not centered anymore. Is there a problem in my code or does tabularx conflict with multicolumn somehow?

[image]

Before and after i tried to use multicolumns. It's just a snippet of the most right column whole table.

Here is the MWE code with the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

% load packages------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} %Schriftart
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{iavgreen}{RGB}{145,198,14}
\definecolor{iavred}{RGB}{206,0,55}
\definecolor{iavgrey}{RGB}{204,204,204}

% Prevent Tables from Floating
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
% New Columntype for Centered Columns
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}} %vertical centering, leftalign
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %vertical and horizontal centering
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %vertical centering let align and linebreak!

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} %no indents
\usepackage[left=2.4cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,right=1.2cm,headheight=90pt]{geometry}
\restylefloat{table}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %TOC depth nur 3 sections

\begin{document}

\section{Ergebnisübersicht}

\begin{small}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.85\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=.12\hsize}X >{\hsize=.62\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.26\hsize}Y|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Test} & & \textbf{Ergebnis}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{2} & \textbf{Kalibriertest Areaview} & !@CalAVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{3} & \textbf{Rearview} &  \\
        \hline
        3.1 &   Kalibriertest Rearview & !@CalRVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.1.1 & Kalibriertest Rearview (Kleine Kalibrierplatte) & !@CalRVSCpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.1.2 & Kalibriertest Rearview (Grosse Kalibrierplatte) & !@CalRVBCpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.1.3 & Ergebnisse der Kalibrierung (fixed values) & !@CalRVFVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.1.4 & Ergebnisse der Kalibrierung (changed values) & !@CalRVCVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.2 & \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Rearview - Parkbox} \\
        \hline
        3.2.1 & Statische Guidelines & !@RVPBSGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.2.2 & Dynamische Guidelines & !@RVPBDGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.3 & \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Rearview - LegalScreen}  \\
        \hline
        3.3.1 & Statische Guidelines & !@RVLSSGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.3.2 & Dynamische Guidelines & !@RVLSDGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.4 &   \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Rearview - Parallel Parking} \\
        \hline
        3.4.1 & Statische Guidelines & !@RVPPSGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.4.2 & Dynamische Guidelines & !@RVPPDGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.5 & \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Rearview - Trailer Coded}  \\
        \hline
        3.5.1 & Satische Guidelines & !@RVTCSGpassed@! \\
        \hline
        3.5.2 & Dynamische Guidelines & !@RVTCDGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.6 & Rearview - Trailer Not Coded & !@RVTNCpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        3.7 & Rearview - Crossing Traffic & !@RVCTpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{4} & \textbf{Frontview} &  \\
        \hline
        4.1 & \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Frontview - Parking Assist}  \\
        \hline
        4.1.1 & Statische Guidelines & !@FVPASGpassed@! \\
        \hline
        4.1.2 & Dynamische Guidelines & !@FVPADGpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        4.2 &   Frontview - Crossing Traffic & !@FVCTpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        4.3 & Frontview - Offroad & !@FVOpassed@! \\
        \hline
        \textbf{5} &    \textbf{Sideview} & !@SVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{6} &    \textbf{2D Birdview} & !@TWODBVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{7} &    \textbf{3D Birdview} & !@THREEDBVpassed@!  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please always post the `MWE` from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`...

Comment: The values next to `\hsize` should add up to the total number of `X` columny. Currently they add up to 1. Also, `small` is not an environment. How is the `Y` column type defined?

Comment: Depending on the textwidth, a simple `\begin{tabular}{lll}` should work as well.

Comment: It worked well before I used the multicolumn inside of the table - that's why I am wondering (just by removing multicolumn and using 2 normal columns would look like the left part of the screenshot). The hsizes worked before perfectly. Y column definition: `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`. And i need to use tabularx for my cell formatting.

Comment: Using `\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=.36\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.86\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.78\hsize}Y|}` with `\hsizes` that add up to 3, the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: See also page 3 of the `tabularx` manual: "However if you want to play games like this you should follow the following two rules. • Make sure that the sum of the widths of all the  X columns is unchanged.  (In the above example, the new widths still add up to twice the default width, the same as two standard X columns.) • Do not use \multicolumn entries which cross any X column."

Comment: Okay so it works partly now, the line offset is gone and the most right column is centered again. But now the multicolumn text (Rearview Parkbox) is offset to the right by some weird margin.

Comment: Please turn the code fragment in your question into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the same output that you get.

Comment: Yeah sure, i edited my code and put in all of the preamble and the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code. I however still get a different output than the one you showed the screensho in your question. Do you somehow replace the contents of the last column with other contents? Please also explain why you need to use `tabularx`. There are alternatives and probably one of them is better suited for this specific table.

Comment: Yes, all of the stuff between !@...@! gets replaced by either "Kein Testumfang", "i.O." or "n.i.O." because the LaTeX Document gets edited and compiled by another program. And i could technically use the normal tabular for this table, what do you suggest? (using normal tabular would need new column definitions for my alignment needs right?)

Comment: Which environment to use entirely depends on the desired output. Currently, your overall table width is fixed. Do you want to keep that fixed width or is it also ok if the table is narrower or wider, provided it still fits into the text width? Regarding the horizontal alignment: The table should be fine if you use `\begin{tabular}{llc}`(In my previous comment I overlooked that the last column is centered instead of left aligned), so no need to define new column types.

Comment: Do the numbers and text in the first and second column correspond to chapters/sections/subsections in your document?

Comment: I used the normal `{llc}` columns now, it does work and is sufficient for my use. Thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.4cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,right=1.2cm,headheight=90pt]{geometry}

% load packages------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} %Schriftart
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, makecell, tabularx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{0.85\linewidth}{|l 
                                  >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X|
                                  >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X|}
        \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Test} 
            &   & \textbf{Ergebnis}  \\
        \Xhline{0.8pt}
\textbf{2}  & \textbf{Kalibriertest Areaview}   
                                        & !@CalAVpassed@!       \\
        \hline \textbf{3}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Rearview}}            \\
        \hline
3.1         & Kalibriertest Rearview    & !@CalRVpassed@!       \\
\hline
3.1.1       & Kalibriertest Rearview (Kleine Kalibrierplatte)
                                        & !@CalRVSCpassed@!     \\
        \hline
3.1.2       & Kalibriertest Rearview (Grosse Kalibrierplatte) 
                                        & !@CalRVBCpassed@!     \\
        \hline
3.1.3       & Ergebnisse der Kalibrierung (fixed values) 
                                        & !@CalRVFVpassed@!     \\
        \hline
3.1.4       & Ergebnisse der Kalibrierung (changed values) 
                                        & !@CalRVCVpassed@!     \\
        \hline
3.2         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Rearview - Parkbox}           \\
        \hline
3.2.1       & Statische Guidelines      & !@RVPBSGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.2.2       & Dynamische Guidelines     & !@RVPBDGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.3         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Rearview - LegalScreen}       \\
        \hline
3.3.1       & Statische Guidelines      & !@RVLSSGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.3.2       & Dynamische Guidelines     & !@RVLSDGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.4         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Rearview - Parallel Parking}  \\
        \hline
3.4.1       & Statische Guidelines      & !@RVPPSGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.4.2       & Dynamische Guidelines     & !@RVPPDGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.5         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Rearview - Trailer Coded}     \\
        \hline
3.5.1       & Satische Guidelines       & !@RVTCSGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.5.2       & Dynamische Guidelines     & !@RVTCDGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
3.6 & Rearview - Trailer Not Coded      & !@RVTNCpassed@!       \\
        \hline
3.7 & Rearview - Crossing Traffic       & !@RVCTpassed@!        \\
        \hline
\textbf{4}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Frontview}}           \\
        \hline
4.1         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Frontview - Parking Assist}   \\
        \hline
4.1.1       & Statische Guidelines      & !@FVPASGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
4.1.2       & Dynamische Guidelines     & !@FVPADGpassed@!      \\
        \hline
4.2         & Frontview - Crossing Traffic
                                        & !@FVCTpassed@!        \\
        \hline
4.3         & Frontview - Offroad       & !@FVOpassed@!         \\
        \hline
\textbf{5}  &    \textbf{Sideview}      & !@SVpassed@!          \\
        \hline
\textbf{6}  &    \textbf{2D Birdview}   & !@TWODBVpassed@!      \\
        \hline
\textbf{7}  &    \textbf{3D Birdview}   & !@THREEDBVpassed@!    \\
        \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This also works for me. Thanks alot too!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (the latest version : 5.2 of 2020-08-19).

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.4cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,right=1.2cm,headheight=90pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{|ll|l|}[hlines]
\textbf{Test} &   & \textbf{Ergebnis}  \\
\textbf{2}   & \textbf{Kalibriertest Areaview} & !@CalAVpassed@! \\
\textbf{3}   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Rearview}}            \\
3.1          & Kalibriertest Rearview    & !@CalRVpassed@!      \\
3.1.1        & Kalibriertest Rearview (Kleine Kalibrierplatte) & !@CalRVSCpassed@! \\
3.1.2        & Kalibriertest Rearview (Grosse Kalibrierplatte) & !@CalRVBCpassed@! \\
3.1.3        & Ergebnisse der Kalibrierung (fixed values) & !@CalRVFVpassed@! \\
3.1.4        & Ergebnisse der Kalibrierung (changed values) & !@CalRVCVpassed@! \\
3.2          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Rearview - Parkbox}           \\
3.2.1        & Statische Guidelines         & !@RVPBSGpassed@!  \\
3.2.2        & Dynamische Guidelines        & !@RVPBDGpassed@!  \\
3.3          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Rearview - LegalScreen}       \\
3.3.1        & Statische Guidelines         & !@RVLSSGpassed@!  \\
3.3.2        & Dynamische Guidelines        & !@RVLSDGpassed@!  \\
3.4          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Rearview - Parallel Parking}  \\
3.4.1        & Statische Guidelines         & !@RVPPSGpassed@!  \\
3.4.2        & Dynamische Guidelines        & !@RVPPDGpassed@!  \\
3.5          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Rearview - Trailer Coded}     \\
3.5.1        & Satische Guidelines          & !@RVTCSGpassed@!  \\
3.5.2        & Dynamische Guidelines        & !@RVTCDGpassed@!  \\
3.6          & Rearview - Trailer Not Coded & !@RVTNCpassed@!   \\
3.7          & Rearview - Crossing Traffic  & !@RVCTpassed@!    \\
\textbf{4}   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Frontview}}           \\
4.1          & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Frontview - Parking Assist}   \\
4.1.1        & Statische Guidelines         & !@FVPASGpassed@!  \\
4.1.2        & Dynamische Guidelines        & !@FVPADGpassed@!  \\
4.2          & Frontview - Crossing Traffic & !@FVCTpassed@!    \\
4.3          & Frontview - Offroad          & !@FVOpassed@!     \\
\textbf{5}   & \textbf{Sideview}            & !@SVpassed@!      \\
\textbf{6}   & \textbf{2D Birdview}         & !@TWODBVpassed@!  \\
\textbf{7}   & \textbf{3D Birdview}         & !@THREEDBVpassed@!\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]